# Fetching cross-domain XML file without JSONP or CORS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xml, json

As part of learning JavaScript, I'm creating a widget to run on my Windows 7 desktop. The widget is supposed to show the time and temperature superimposed on a webcam image. The webcam image and the temperature are pulled from separate, remote servers (both reliable and known safe). The temperature is part of an XML file, and needs to be parsed to get the temperature from it.

Here's the snippet of code that's giving me issues.

```
function setTemp(locURL) {
    $.ajax({
        url : locURL,
        success : function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            // repackage plainobject as String and send for parsing
            displayTemp(String(data));
        },
        error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(errorThrown);
        }
    });
}
```

The parameter `locURL` is passed as a String containing the location of the XML file, locally or remote. When the XML file is hosted locally, there's no problem; the widget works perfectly. When I try and pull the XML file from the remote server, however, I run into the cross-domain security issue.

Is there a way to get this XML file from the remote server? I don't have admin rights to the remote host, and they offer no JSONP support. So, neither JSONP nor CORS are useful options. Could there be a simple HTML solution that I'm not thinking of?

Comment: Your only other option is to use a local server-side script to retrieve the XML file, then fetch that local script via AJAX.

Comment: Do you have access to a web server where you could host a page to download the xml file for you, and have that allow CORS?

Comment: *"Could there be a simple HTML solution that I'm not thinking of?"* Nope. There's nothing you can do client-side to make this work. Do it server-side.

Comment: What if I don't have admin rights locally, either? There's really no way to put a temperature on top of an image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there isn't. That's what the [Same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) is for: Making sure that you can't.

You need to add a HTTP client library to your own server which downloads the file and makes it available under a domain which you control (after asking for permission to use the data, of course).

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have admin rights to the web server or even this particular machine, either. Is there no way to do this completely from the client? It seems strange that there's no way to pull two pieces of data from remote servers and combine them using only client code.

Comment: As I said, this is by design. If it was possible, then security on the web would be even worse because hackers could inject JavaScript into web pages from anywhere. As it is, they have to break the server, first.